# How to get the NA while we exclude them for analysis

Tags: r

I have a large column with NAs, I want to rank the time as shown below. I want to keep NAs while I exclude them from the analysis,

```
 df<-read.table(text="time
    40
    30
    50
    NA
    60
    NA
    20
    ", header=True)
```

I want to get the following table:

```
 time   Rank
    40  3
    30  4
    50  2
    NA  NA
    60  1
    NA  NA
    20  5
```

I have used the following code:

```
df$Rank<--df$time,ties.method="mim")
```

Comment: Your *"following code"* seems to be missing the function itself. Further, `header=True` is a syntax error; either you have `True` defined as a user variable in your environment, or you are typing unused code here in SO and that should be `header=TRUE`. *Please* include "real code" that you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#fixed data
df<-read.table(text="time
     40
     30
     50
     NA
     60
     NA
     20
     ", header=TRUE)
```

You can do something like

```
nonNaIndices <- !is.na(df$time)
df$Rank <- NA
df$Rank[nonNaIndices] <- rank(df$time[nonNaIndices],ties.method="min")
```

resulting in

```
> df
  time Rank
1   40    3
2   30    2
3   50    4
4   NA   NA
5   60    5
6   NA   NA
7   20    1
```

Note: Please make sure to check your question for missing function calls before submitting it. In your case it could be guessed from the context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dense_rank` from `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(Rank = dense_rank(-time))

#  time Rank
#1   40    3
#2   30    4
#3   50    2
#4   NA   NA
#5   60    1
#6   NA   NA
#7   20    5
```